# If $R$ be a Union of zero measure sets , what is the cardinal of index set?

Tags: set-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $R$ be a Union of zero measure (lebesgue) sets , what can we say about the cardinal of index set? Does this question related to continuum hypothesis? Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\kappa$ is a cardinal such that $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \kappa} A_\alpha$, where each $A_\alpha$ is measure zero. Then $\kappa$ is greater than equal to a cardinal called $\text{cov(null)}$, which is by definition the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that there exists a family $\{A_\alpha : \alpha < \kappa\}$ of null sets whose union is $\mathbb{R}$.

It is clear that $\text{cov(null)} > \aleph_0$. Hence if the continuum hypothesis is true then, $\text{cov(null)} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.

However, there are models (where the continuum hypothesis is false) in which $\text{cov(null)} < 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Where I can find this result , thanks.

Comment: This can be proved using iterated forcing. I believe Combinatorial Set Theory by Halbeisen should have a proof of this result.

Comment: @hctb By the way, one explicit example is to start off the with the constructible universe $L$ as forcing using the $\omega_2$ length countable support iteration of Sacks forcing (perfect trees).

Comment: @hctb Also it is possible for the continuum hypothesis to be false and $\text{cov(null)} = 2^{\aleph_0}$. For this you can use an $\omega_2$ length countable support iteration of Random forcing over $L$.